# How to url encode the binary contents of a video in Python?

Tags: python, tumblr

I wanted to port video to Tumblr using the API using the [Tumblpy library](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-tumblpy).

My code is this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(video-url)
f = {'data':r.content}
dat = urllib.urlencode(f)


t.post('post', blog_url='http://tumblrname.tumblr.com/',params={'type':'video', 
            'title':post.title, 'slug': post.slug,'date':post.date,'data':dat,'tags':post.tagscsv,
                'caption': post.body_html}) #t is TumblPy instance
```

Well, I am not being successful in this. I do think I am missing out on how to encode the binary contents to make the post successful, though I am not sure.

Comment: Please format your code correctly! Can you also show the traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it's going to be similar to how you post a photo, in which case the library wants a file(like) object. A `requests` response can act as a file-like object just fine:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(video_url)

t.post('post', blog_url='http://tumblrname.tumblr.com/', 
    params={'type': 'video', 'title': post.title, 'slug': post.slug, 
            'date': post.date, 'data': r.raw, 'tags': post.tagscsv,
            'caption': post.body_html})
```

where `r.raw` gives you a file-like object that, when read, yields the video data read from `video_url`.

Comment: Did it work for you? For me it didn't. Gave a 401 Not Authorized error.

Comment: I presume this happens because the encoding of the video isn't fine as the same oauth token and secret for all other types of posts.

Comment: @Hick: I don't *have* a Tumblr account, so I didn't test anything. I merely looked at how it handles file uploads.

Comment: I was going through the TumblPy library that handles with file uploads and thought that it might be doing wrong there. Because I get similar errors while uplooading a photo too. Any file content fails. Do you think the TumblPy library is getting it wrong?

Comment: @Hick: I don't actually know. the [API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting) certainly supports uploading a `data` component. I see [others having these issues too](https://groups.google.com/group/tumblr-api/tree/browse_frm/month/2012-01/6f16c305008b938b?rnum=51&_done=/group/tumblr-api/browse_frm/month/2012-01?&pli=1) but that's now over a year ago.

Comment: Yes, was going through that and everyone had a different explanation. Hence, I came here. Sigh! Guess that is a dead end. Thanks for the help, though!